# Input manipulation for an alias

Tags: alias, man

`man -k '^printf'` lists man pages specifically available for printf utility only, `printf(1)` and `printf(3)` in my PC. If you do not mention these signs around printf, the command doesn't work.

I want to make an alias `mank` for this but I am stuck at the logic.

I want to be able to type `mank utility` and have the same output as `man -k '^utility'`.

This way without typing silly symbols, we would get all the man pages available for that utility.

Comment: Can you use a function instead?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I don't know any function, I am a newbie. If you know, let me know..

Comment: You could consider `alias mank=apropos`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the old `alias`, then make a function, and run it:

```
unalias mank
mank() { man -k "^$1" ; }
mank printf
```

Output:

```
printf (1)           - format and print data
printf (1posix)      - write formatted output
printf (3)           - formatted output conversion
printf (3posix)      - print formatted output
```